# Public Images not showing production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have deployed my rails application (rails version - 5.0) to AWS elastic beanstalk. I have few images that are static and are in public/images folder , Its not showing in production 
environment (server), although i have precompiled the assets with rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production and i also put my images folder in the assets folder as well 
but the images are not showing, Please help me I need to release the version before midnight.
I am posting the link of my website running on production server
 Please see to it :
http://web-app-dev-env.b2gs2j58ux.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/

Answer (score 0):

Damn such a silly mistake , in my production.rb i had to comment out this line :
  #config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

and add this line and it worked fine :
 config.serve_static_assets = true